# What is the ECMAScript version supported in Cloudant (or CouchDB) design documents?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

The title contains the full question actually.

In CouchDB (and Cloudant in particular) you write design documents with views using JavaScript. What is the supported ECMAScript version there?

I could not find a relevant documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that Mozilla Spider Monkey is used for executing the design documents.

The [build documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/install/unix.html) for CouchDB 2.0 state Mozilla Spider Monkey 1.8.5 as a dependency.

You can find the [release notes for 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/1.8.5) contain the following:

> SpiderMonkey 1.8.5 is the JavaScript engine that shipped in Firefox 4.0. It is much faster than SpiderMonkey 1.8, implements ES-5 (ECMA 262, 5th Edition), and contains many new language and API features, described in detail below.

You could maybe post a separate question with the [[spidermonkey]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spidermonkey) tag to see if there is a javascript api method you can call to retrieve the spider monkey version via javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the research and the detailed answer. I think your answer deplted the topic, but I opened another question as per your suggestion out of curiosity :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339772/javascript-api-to-check-spidermonkey-version