# Javascript API to check SpiderMonkey version

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

Is there some API I could call from a JavaScript to check which version of SpiderMonkey it is executed on ?

Comment: Where is that JavaScript code running? In the browser or in the SpiderMonkey shell?

Comment: @evilpie Neither. It's used in CouchDB & Cloudant databases for processing database views.